Density result in $ L^2(a,b;H_0^1(\Omega)) \bigcap C([a,b];L^2(\Omega))$
I want to prove the following proposition, but I face some gaps.
Proposition  $\ \ \Omega$  is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R^n}.$
Let $u \in$ $L^{2}((a,b);H_{0}^{1}(\Omega))\cap C([a,b];L^{2}(\Omega))\ $.
(i) For any $\delta > 0$, there exists $\Phi\in C^{\infty}([a,b];D(\Omega))$ such that
$\left\lVert u-\Phi\right\rVert_{C([a,b];L^{2}(\Omega))}\leq\delta $ and
$ \left\lVert\nabla u-\nabla\Phi\right\rVert_{L^{2}(\Omega\times[a,b])}\leq\delta .$
where $C^{\infty}([a,b];D(\Omega))$ is the space of measurable functions on $\Omega\times[a,b]$ such that $u(\cdot,t)\in D(\Omega)$ for any $t\in[a,b]$, and such that the map $ t\in[a,b]\to u(\cdot,t)\in D(\Omega) $ is indefinitely differentiable, $D(\Omega):=C_c^{\infty}(\Omega).$
(ii) If further $u'\in C([a,b];L^{2}(\Omega))$, then for any $\delta > 0$, there exists $\Phi\in C^{\infty}([a,b];D(\Omega))$ such that
$\left\lVert u'-\Phi'\right\rVert_{C([a,b];L^{2}(\Omega))}\leq\delta$ and $\left\lVert\nabla u-\nabla\Phi\right\rVert_{L^{2}(\Omega\times[a,b])}\leq\delta. $
I try two ways:
1.mollify in time then mollify in space. However, when I mollify in spcae, I can't guarantee it has a compact support set.
2.approximate in space then mollify in time. $\forall \delta >0$, fixed $t \in [a,b]$, there exists $v(x,t) \in D(\Omega)$ such that $||u(x,t)-v(x,t)||_{L^2(\Omega)}<\delta.$ When I mollify in time, $\alpha_{\epsilon}(t)*v(x,t)$, I can't prove it belong to $D(\Omega).$
This proposition is in the book "Doina Cioranescu-An Introduction to homogenization" $P_{63}$ Proposition 3.60. In this book, authors did not give the proof and did not give the reference of this proposition.

To prove it, it is better to see elements of Sobolev spaces, not as measurable function but as element of a Banach space defined as the completion of $C^\infty([a,b],D(\Omega))$.
Claim : If $V$ is a vector space, $N_1$ and $N_2$ are norms on $V$, $V_1$ is the completion of $(V,N_1)$, $V_2$ is the completion of $(V,N_2)$ and $V_{12}$ is the completion of $(V,N_1 + N_2)$, the natural injections $V \rightarrow V_1$ and $V \rightarrow V_2$ factorise as,
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
(V,N_1 + N_2) &&&&\\
& \searrow &&&\\
&& (V_{12},N_1 + N_2) & \rightarrow & (V_1,N_1)\\
&& \downarrow &&\\
&& (V_2,N_2) &&
\end{array}
$$
where $V \rightarrow V_{12}$ is the natural injection and all the maps here are continuous injective linear maps. Moreover, $(V_{12},N_1 + N_2)$ is minimal for this property in the following sens. For all normed vector space $(W,N)$ such that we have a diagram of the form,
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
(V,N_1 + N_2) &&&&\\
& \searrow &&&\\
&& (W,N) & \rightarrow & (V_1,N_1)\\
&& \downarrow &&\\
&& (V_2,N_2) &&
\end{array}
$$
where the maps are linear and continuous injections, the diagram can be extended as,
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
(W,N) &&&&\\
& \searrow &&&\\
&& (V_{12},N_1 + N_2) & \rightarrow & (V_1,N_1)\\
&& \downarrow &&\\
&& (V_2,N_2) &&
\end{array}
$$
where once again, everything is continuous, linear and injective. Notice that it is just a complicated (but rigourous) way to say that $V_{12} = V_1 \cap V_2$.
To prove it, we need first to construct the maps $V_{12} \rightarrow V_1$ and $V_{12} \rightarrow V_2$. The map $(V,N_1) \rightarrow (V_1,N_1)$ is continuous (it is an isometry) thus the map $(V,N_1 + N_2) \rightarrow (V_1,N_1)$ is continuous too (it is trivially $1$-Lipschitz). Therefore, we may extend it uniquely by continuity as a continuous map $(V_{12},N_1 + N_2) \rightarrow (V_1,N_1)$. Similarly, we build a continuous map $(V_{12},N_1 + N_2) \rightarrow (V_2,N_2)$.
For the last statement, assume we have $(W,N)$ as above. The continuity assumption tells you that for all $w \in W$, $N_1(w) \leqslant C_1N(w)$ and $N_2(w) \leqslant C_2N(w)$ for some $C_1,C_2 > 0$ independant from $w$. Therefore, $(N_1 + N_2)(w) \leqslant \max\{C_1,C_2\}N(w)$. It show that $(V,N_1 + N_2) \rightarrow (W,N)$ is not only continuous, it is also open. Therefore, they have the same completion so we obtain injective continuous maps $(V,N_1 + N_2) \rightarrow (W,N) \rightarrow (V_{12},N_1 + N_2)$ where the composition $V \rightarrow V_{12}$ is the natural injection. It proves the second point.
Apply the claim with $V = \mathcal{C}^\infty([a,b],\mathcal{D}(\Omega))$, $N_1 = \|\cdot\|_{C([a,b],L^2(\Omega))}$ and $N_2 = \|\cdot\|_{L^2([a,b],H_0^1(\Omega))}$. We obtain a diagram as above which show that $C([a,b],L^2(\Omega)) \cap L^2([a,b],H_0^1(\Omega))$ is exactly the completion of $V$ with respect to the norm $N_1 + N_2$ which is exactly your desired result.
Concretely, let $u \in V_1 \cap V_2$ and $W = V \oplus \mathbb{R}u$ endowed with the $N_1 + N_2$ norm. By the claim above, the natural injection $V \rightarrow W$ must be dense so for all $\delta > 0$, you may find $\Phi \in V$ such that,
$$
\|u - \Phi\|_{C([a,b],L^2(\Omega))} + \|u - \Phi\|_{L^2([a,b],H_0^1(\Omega))} \leqslant \delta.
$$
It easily leads to the result you want. The exact same proof works for the second point you want to prove. It actually works for any pair of Sobolev/Hölder/$C^k$ norm for example.

Thank you! You give a good structure.
